# Shell error when using multiline ssh command inside user prompt check

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

Running into a bit of an issue while trying to add a user prompt check to a existing script which was already working.

Here is the existing script, which is **working**...

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "**** Pulling changes into Production"

ssh user@example.com "$( cat <<'EOT'
    cd example.com/html/ || exit
    unset GIT_DIR
    git pull
EOT
)"
```

Here is my modified script with a user prompt, which is **broken**.. and it is only broken when I add the ssh line. Works perfectly with just echoes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true; do
    read -p "Are you sure you want to pull changes into production? [y/N] " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) 
            ssh user@example.com "$( cat <<'EOT'
                cd example.com/html/ || exit
                unset GIT_DIR
                git pull
                EOT
            )"; 
            exit;;
        [Nn]* ) 
            echo "!!!! CANCELLING !!!!"; 
            exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

The error I'm getting is...

```
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EOT` must appear at the beginning of the line. Your `EOT` appears somewhere in between, with lots of leading spaces.

Replace

```
                EOT
```

By

```
EOT
```

Comment: I would move the ssh part to a function and call that function from the case expression.

Comment: That's what I get for trying to make the code look clean! Thank you!